# Header/Title bar get off when use keyboard on Phonegap

Tags: css, cordova

It's a unexpected behavior sometimes when the keyboard is open (in iOS and Android):

[image]

I don't know if it can be fixed with css styles or with a phonegap's configuration (something like `<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`)

Thanks